# Groovy - condense multiple if statements

Tags: java, groovy

I'm a groovy newbie so bear with me here. I love groovy's power to write less and often cleaner code but I'm trying to figure out if there's a better or more readable way of condensing these multiple if statements. It's a fairly straightforward code snippet but there's got to be a better way of doing this. I'm a newbie so any code snippets are greatly appreciated.

```
if (!textOverlay) {
  textType = "" 
  if(url != null){
    Page getPage = resource.getResourceResolver().getResource(url).adaptTo(Page.class)
    if (getPage != null) {
      showLink = showLink + ".html"
        if (fragment.length() > 0) {
          url += "#"+fragment;
        }
    }
  }             
}  else { 
    //do something else
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I don't see how it could be more compact and still be readable. What's wrong with that code? Except that it seems to have many responsibilities (many variables that seem unrelated), I don't see any code duplication.

Comment: You should consider using `URI` instead of building the URL by hand... It will take of all the pesky stuff like encoding etc. And its constructors are "null-resistant"

Comment: I was always under the impression and I could be wrong that it was bad practice to have multiple nested if statements.  Thanks for the tip @fge

Comment: It indeed increases the code complexity. But the solution is not to "compact" them. The solution is to isolate the responsibilities into other sub-methods: `if (textOverlay) { doSomething(); } else { doSomethingElse(); }`. Apply this rule recursively until you have methods which have a unique, clear responsibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't help with nesting, but there are a few places where you could take advantage of Groovy to make the code a bit more compact. I've added some explanatory comments

```
if (!textOverlay) {
  textType = "" 

  // null is considered false, so no need to explicitly check for null
  if (url) {

    // getResourceResolver() replaced by resourceResolver
    // Page and Page.class are the same thing
    Page getPage = resource.resourceResolver.getResource(url).adaptTo(Page)

    // Groovy truth
    if (getPage) {

      // use String concatenation operator (also works in Java)
      showLink += ".html"

      // non-empty strings evaluate to true
      if (fragment) {
          // GString instead of string concatenation
          url += "#$fragment"
      }
    }
  }             
}  else { 
    //do something else
}
```